# Is there a BibTeX "schema" somewhere?

Tags: bibtex, zotero

Is there some specification of BibTeX fields and best practices for using them? E.g. I see people using `eprint`, is this specified somewhere?

E.g. `bibtexml` is supposed to provide schemes for BibTeX, but [bibtexconverter-0.5-schema.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bibtexml/files/BibTeXConverter-extras/bibtexconverter%200.5/bibtexconverter-0.5-schema.zip/download) `schema\bibtexml-generic.rnc` doesn't know about `eprint`.

Comment: Is the description on [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management) what you were looking for?

Comment: The `biblatex` manual is also pretty good. Check out `texdoc biblatex` (or, for that matter, `texdoc bibtex`)

Comment: `bibtex` does not support `eprint` unless there is some specialised style which does so. It certainly is not a standard `bibtex` field. `biblatex`, on the other hand, does. Documentation as specified by Sean Allred.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Entry_and_field_types_in_.bib_files . More details in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf p7 onwards

Answer (score 4):

BibTeX very deliberately does not enforce any particular field names: fields which are recognised are dependent on the style (`.bst`) file in use and all others are ignored. Several fields have been used for many years (starting with the 'core' styles) and so are 'standard', for example `author`, `title`, `year`. Some related to electronic publication (which post-dates the initial release of BibTeX) have become standard over time, for example `url`, although they *do not* appear in the 'core' styles. However, as there is no enforcement of such things it remains down to the individual style author to define which fields are recognised/required/...